# Using MiniProfiler with MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

**Edit**
Got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790507/miniprofiler-not-showing-up-on-asp-net-mvc?rq=1)

So I wanted to check out MiniProfiler to troubleshoot some performance issues.
Before using it on production code I wanted to try it out with the a sample so went ahead with creating a MVC 5 application. This is plain vanilla app that gets created with the template.

Added this code in the Index() method of HomeController:

```
var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
        using (profiler.Step("Set page title"))
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        }
        using (profiler.Step("Doing complex stuff"))
        {
            using (profiler.Step("Step A"))
            { // something more interesting here
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            using (profiler.Step("Step B"))
            { // and here
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }
        }
        return View();
```

Added this line below the jquery bundle in _Layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Ran the app.
Nothing shows up. No profiling, nothing.

What am I missing?

Regards.

Answer (score 30):

This is what I had to do to get MiniProfiler working in my **ASP.NET MVC5** project:

1. Installed the **MiniProfiler** and **MiniProfiler.MVC4** NuGet packages (the MVC4 package supports MVC5)
2. Add the following to `Application_Start()` in Global.asax:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       ...
       // Setup profiler for Controllers via a Global ActionFilter
       GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ProfilingActionFilter());

       // initialize automatic view profiling
       var copy = ViewEngines.Engines.ToList();
       ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
       foreach (var item in copy)
       {
           ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ProfilingViewEngine(item));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the following to 'Application_BeginRequest()' and 'Application_EndRequest()', also in Global.asax:

   ```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest()
   {
       if (Request.IsLocal)
       {
           MiniProfiler.Start();
       }
   }

   protected void Application_EndRequest()
   {
       MiniProfiler.Stop();
   }
   ```
4. Add the following to _Layout.cshtml (just before the `</body>` tag):

   ```
       ...
       @StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
5. Add the following to the `<handlers>` section of Web.config:

   ```
   <system.webServer>
       ...
       <handlers>
           ...
           <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*"
                type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified"
                preCondition="integratedMode" />
           ...
       </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
   ```

That was enough to profile each of the MVC Controller Actions and Views.

---

In my particular project I was using Entity Framework 6, so I also did the following:

a) Installed the **MiniProfiler.EF6** package

b) Added the following to the end of `Application_Start()` in Global.asax:

```
    ...
    MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't aware of the possibility for automatic controller & view profiling

Answer (score 5):

Also you have to add call:

```
MiniProfiler.Start();
```

In Global.asax.cs to Application_BeginRequest event.

And:

```
MiniProfiler.Stop();
```

In Global.asax.cs to Application_EndRequest event.