# Upgrade to MiniProfiler 3.2 from 2.1 no longer shows child

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I recently upgraded miniprofiler to the latest version and it is no longer automatically creating children steps for various MVC related things. Before it would show the timings of all the actions and child actions for a request, as well as the timing for the finding of views, and rendering of views. In the new version, it is only showing the timing of the entire request. The older version displayed this information automatically.

Does this level of detail exist in the newer version? How do you enable it?

Old version:

[image: old version]

New version:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding this when I register my action filters in MVC:

`GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new StackExchange.Profiling.Mvc.ProfilingActionFilter());`

Which I found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18790728/453449